# Move the row to bottom of table on selection?

Tags: ios, swift

I like to move the row to `bottom` of the `table` and `persist` it that is I like it to see my changes when I come to my screen again, if the `eventStatus == 1 0r 2`. I did the following but the rows are not moving

```
   if eventSegCtrl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.text = self.eventScheduleOnc[indexPath.row].eventNameOnc
                let eventDesc = self.eventScheduleOnc[indexPath.row].eventDecOnc

                let eventStatus = eventDesc?.eventStatus
            if eventStatus == 1 {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.green
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
                }
            }
            else if eventStatus == 2 {
                myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
                }
            }
        else {
            myEventCell.eventLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Hi. Do you want to scroll down to your last row, or move the item at 0 to the end of your array of objects?

Comment: Actually move the item at 0 to the end of my array of objects

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Comment: @Coder221 Is your problem solved?

Comment: @NiravD , No none of the solutions worked for me, you mind helping me out on this

Answer (score 0):

You are scrolling to `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` which means the first row of the first section, which means it will scroll to top.

If you only have 1 section, change this:

```
IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
```

into

```
let numberOfRows  // How many rows you have?
IndexPath(row: numberOfRows - 1, section: 0)
```

If you have multiple sections and multiple rows, change into these instead:

```
let numberOfSections // How many sections you have
let numberOfRowsInLastSection = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection:numberOfSections-1)
IndexPath(row: numberOfRowsInLastSection-1, section: numberOfSections-1)
```

Comment: I have 1 section and tried IndexPath(row: numberOfRows - 1, section: 0) but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .bottom, animated: true)
```

does not move a single row, it tries to scroll the entire table view in a way that the row at the given index path (0,0) is located a the given position (bottom).

It sounds you would like to reorder the cells. In order to do so you have to:

1. adjust your data model.
2. either reload the entire table (this is not animated) or call

Swift:

```
func moveRow(at indexPath: IndexPath, 
          to newIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: Is there any sample you can direct me to adjust my data model

Comment: @Coder221: That depends on what you're using as data model. If it's a simple array, you need to remove the entry at it's current location and add it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to move row, you need to do this.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
      return true}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      var itemToMove = tableData[fromIndexPath.row]
      tableData.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
      tableData.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)
}
```

Comment: What you are using is scrollToRow at indexPath. It literally just scrolls the view to a path that you specify. You need to use the above to do what you want to do.

Comment: Also item to move == eventDesc. And tableData == eventScheduleOnc.

Comment: Tried it, but I don't see any change

Comment: It should work. Please check your code. I've used this a couple of times on multiple apps.

Comment: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/reordering-rows-table-view-ios8-swift.

Comment: Maybe the startEditing is what you need. This should fix your problem.

Comment: You got me wrong. I am not doing it manually as show in example, it has to be done automatically

Comment: Ohh! Then just do a check like youve already done, and write

if eventStatus == 1 {
               var itemToMove = eventScheduleOnc[from: 0]
      eventScheduleOnc.removeAtIndex(from: 0)
      eventScheduleOnc.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: eventScheduleOnc.count - 1) (or -2) if second last. Basically if 10 items, move to position 9 or 8)
}